# how to remove form tools in ckeditor and also make size adjustable

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKE Editor in my project. My requirement is to remove "`FORM TOOLS`" and make size of the CKE Editor `ADJUSTABLE` . So far I have displayed editor in web page successfully. I have searched google but unluckily i have got nothing. kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found one solution by reading documentation,

I added following configuration in config.js,

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:


         CKEDITOR.config.resize_enabled = true;
         CKEDITOR.config.width = 600;
         CKEDITOR.config.autoGrow_minHeight = 600;
         CKEDITOR.config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 600;
         CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_Full =
[
    ['Source','-','Save','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates'],
    ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
    ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
//  ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField'], // here i disable the form tools
    '/',
    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote','CreateDiv'],
    ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
    ['BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl' ],
    ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
    ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe'],
    '/',
    ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],
    ['TextColor','BGColor'],
    ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About']
];
};
```

Answer (score 7):

just try this

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.removePlugins = 'forms';
};
```