# Remove the unwanted options like image uploading etc In codeigniter ckeditor

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor

I am using codeigniter Ckediter. I just want to remove the unwanted tools in that. I have searched in google and tried many ways , but i didnt get the proper solution to do it.

My ckediter code:

```
function cke_create_instance($data = array()) {

    $return = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    CKEDITOR.replace('" . $data['id'] . "', {";

    //Adding config values
    if(isset($data['config'])) {
        foreach($data['config'] as $k=>$v) {

            // Support for extra config parameters
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $return .= $k . " : [";
                $return .= config_data($v);
                $return .= "]"; 
            }
            else {
                $return .= $k . " : '" . $v . "'";
            }

            if($k !== end(array_keys($data['config']))) {
                $return .= ",";
            }                       
        } 
    }               

    $return .= '});</script>';  

    return $return;
}
```

Can anyone help me??
thanks in advance..

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305561/how-to-remove-form-tools-in-ckeditor-and-also-make-size-adjustable

Comment: That is not working.